# How to get text file using .each method,

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:
I want to $.get a .txt file with the same name as the div id and show in the respective divs
But is returning the same file to all the divs, also is loading the last file/div id.

How can I achieve this?

```
    <div class="addId" id="qwerty" ><div class="parent"></div></div>
    <div class="addId" id="ytrewq" ><div class="parent"></div></div>
    <div class="addId" id="asdfgh" ><div class="parent"></div></div>
    <div class="addId" id="bruno" ><div class="parent"></div></div>
```

and this script:

```
function loadTxt(){
    $('.parent').each(function(){
    var txtId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $.get( "./"+txtId+'.txt', function( data ) { var resourceContent = data; 
    $('.parent').html(data)}) }) };
```

Comment: Hi here `$('.parent').html(data)` is targetting all classes .Instead declare `var selector=$(this)` outside your ajax call and then inside use `selector.html(data)` this will target only particular class.

Comment: worked fine, thanks! I was struggling to achieve this and it's pretty simple! Thank you again!